# Error before executing the submit handler

Tags: 8, forms

i've made a custom form by including into it a node creation form and the user profile form. But when i try to submit my form i get this error :

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() must be of the type array, null given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fritr/core/modules/file/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/FileWidget.php on line 332 in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 71 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).
```

I don't know what to do to fix that and it has been a week i work on fix this error... I need your help.

Here is my code :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\fritr_register_friterie\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Class RegisterFriterieForm.
 *
 * @package Drupal\fritr_register_friterie\Form
 */
class RegisterFriterieForm extends FormBase {

    protected $sub_forms = [];

    /**
     * Le constructeur va initialiser nos deux objets innerForm qui sont :
     *  - User
     *  - Content type : Friterie
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
        $this->sub_forms['user'] = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($user);
        $entity = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->create(array(
            'type' => node_type_load('friterie')->id(),
        ));
        $this->sub_forms['friterie'] = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'register_friterie_form';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        // Champ vérification propriétaire
        $form['proprietaire'] = array(
            '#type' => 'radios',
            '#title' => t('Êtes-vous le propriétaire de cette friterie ?'),
            '#options' => array(
                t('Oui'),
                t('Non'),
            ),
            '#attributes' => array(
                'class' => array('clear-panel-field panel-field-inline container-inline'),
            ),
            '#default_value' => 1,
            '#required' => TRUE
        );

        $sub_forms_keys = array_keys($this->sub_forms);
        // INC ALL SUBFORM INTO THE MAIN FORM
        foreach ($this->sub_forms as $key => $sub_form) {
            // REMOVE THE PROCESS CALLBACK
            if (!empty($sub_form['#process'])) {
                unset($sub_form['#process']);
            }

            // ALTER THE SUBFORM
            if ($key == $sub_forms_keys[0]) { // user Alter
                foreach ($sub_form as $field_key => $sub_form_field) { // Pour tous les champs                
                    if (substr($field_key, 0, 10) != 'field_user') { // Si ce n'est pas un champ personnalisé user
                        unset($sub_form[$field_key]); // Cacher le champ
                    } else { // Si c'est un champ user
                        // Cacher les label
                        $sub_form[$field_key]['#attributes'] = array(
                            'class' => array('no-label'),
                        );
                        if (array_key_exists('widget', $sub_form[$field_key])) { // Si c'est un champ user et qu'il dispose d'un widget
                            $sub_form_field_widget = $sub_form[$field_key]['widget'][0];
                            $sub_form_field_widget['value']['#states'] = array(
                                'visible' => array(':input[#edit-proprietaire-0]' => array('checked' => true))
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
                // subform title
                $sub_form['title']['#markup'] = '<p class="form-info">Informations responsable <span>(Obligatoire)</span></p>';
            }
            if ($key == $sub_forms_keys[1]) { // Friterie Alter
                foreach ($sub_form as $field_key => $sub_form_field) { // Pour tous les champs                
                    if (substr($field_key, 0, 14) != 'field_friterie') { // Si ce n'est pas un champ personnalisé friterie
                        unset($sub_form[$field_key]); // Cacher le champ
                    } else if (array_key_exists('widget', $sub_form[$field_key])) { // Si c'est un champ friterie et qu'il dispose d'un widget                        
                    }
                }
                // subform title
                $sub_form['title']['#markup'] = '<p class="form-info">Informations friterie <span>(Obligatoire)</span></p>';

                // Gestion préfix / suffix
                $sub_form['field_friterie_pays']['#prefix'] = '<div class="row">';
                $sub_form['field_friterie_ville']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
                $sub_form['field_friterie_nom']['#prefix'] = '<div>';
                $sub_form['field_friterie_telephone']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
                $sub_form['field_friterie_menu_frites']['#prefix'] = '<p class="form-info">Menus <span>(Facultatif)</span></p><div class="row">';
                $sub_form['field_friterie_menu_autre']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

                // Gestion class
                $sub_form['field_friterie_pays']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 no-label'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_code_postal']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 no-label'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_ville']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 no-label'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_adresse']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('no-label'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_nom']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('mid-display no-label'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_telephone']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('mid-display no-label'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_menu_frites']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_menu_viande']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_menu_sandwich']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_menu_autre']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_paiement_type']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('clear-panel-field third-display hide-required logo-checkboxes-container'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_budget']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('clear-panel-field panel-field-inline'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_sur_place']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('clear-panel-field panel-field-inline'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_photos_free']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('clear-panel-field'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_photos_pay_conf']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('clear-panel-field'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_photos_pay']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('clear-panel-field'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_site_web']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('inline-label'),
                );
                $sub_form['field_friterie_facebook']['#attributes'] = array(
                    'class' => array('inline-label'),
                );
            }

            // ADD THE SUBFORM INTO THE MAIN FORM
            $form[$key] = [
                '#type' => 'container',
                'form' => $sub_form
            ];
        }

        $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
        $form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Cancel'),
            '#button_type' => 'cancel',
            '#submit' => '::cancelForm',
        );
        $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Submit'),
            '#button_type' => 'primary',
        );

        return $form;
    }

    public function cancelForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        drupal_set_message("cancel");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        drupal_set_message("validate");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        drupal_set_message("submitted");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix my bug by using a strong system of exclusion of non desired fields :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\fritr_register_friterie\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Class RegisterFriterieForm.
 *
 * @package Drupal\fritr_register_friterie\Form
 */
class RegisterFriterieForm extends FormBase {

    protected $sub_forms = [];

    /**
     * Le constructeur va initialiser nos deux objets innerForm qui sont :
     *  - User
     *  - Content type : Friterie
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
        $this->sub_forms['user'] = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($user);
        $entity = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->create(array(
            'type' => node_type_load('friterie')->id(),
        ));
        $this->sub_forms['friterie'] = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'register_friterie_form';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        // Champ vérification propriétaire
        $form['proprietaire'] = array(
            '#type' => 'radios',
            '#title' => t('Êtes-vous le propriétaire de cette friterie ?'),
            '#options' => array(
                t('Oui'),
                t('Non'),
            ),
            '#attributes' => array(
                'class' => array('clear-panel-field panel-field-inline container-inline'),
            ),
            '#default_value' => 1,
            '#required' => TRUE
        );

        $sub_forms_keys = array_keys($this->sub_forms);
        // INC ALL SUBFORM INTO THE MAIN FORM
        foreach ($this->sub_forms as $key => $sub_form) {
            // REMOVE THE PROCESS CALLBACK
            if (!empty($sub_form['#process'])) {
                unset($sub_form['#process']);
            }

            // ALTER THE SUBFORM
            if ($key == $sub_forms_keys[0]) { // user Alter
                $form[$key]['title']['#markup'] = '<p class="form-info">Informations responsable <span>(Obligatoire)</span></p>';
                foreach ($sub_form as $field_key => $sub_form_field) { // Pour tous les champs                
                    if (substr($field_key, 0, 10) != 'field_user') { // Si ce n'est pas un champ personnalisé user
                        unset($sub_form[$field_key]); // Cacher le champ
                    } else { // Si c'est un champ user
                        if (array_key_exists('widget', $sub_form[$field_key])) { // Si c'est un champ user et qu'il dispose d'un widget
                            // ON FILTRE LES WIDGETS POUR N'AJOUTER QUE LES CHAMPS DESIRES
                            $sub_form_field_widget = $sub_form[$field_key]['widget'];
                            if (array_key_exists('0', $sub_form_field_widget)) {
                                $sub_form_field_widget = $sub_form_field_widget[0];
                                if (array_key_exists('value', $sub_form_field_widget)) {
                                    // ON AJOUTE LE CHAMP AU FORMULAIRE
                                    $form[$key][$field_key] = $sub_form[$field_key];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            dsm('10');
            if ($key == $sub_forms_keys[1]) { // Friterie Alter
                foreach ($sub_form as $field_key => $sub_form_field) { // Pour tous les champs                
                    if (substr($field_key, 0, 14) != 'field_friterie') { // Si ce n'est pas un champ personnalisé friterie
                        unset($sub_form[$field_key]); // Cacher le champ
                    } else if (array_key_exists('widget', $sub_form[$field_key])) { // Si c'est un champ friterie et qu'il dispose d'un widget                                                                       
                        // ON FILTRE LES WIDGETS POUR N'AJOUTER QUE LES CHAMPS DESIRES
                        $sub_form_field_widget = $sub_form[$field_key]['widget'];
                        if (array_key_exists('0', $sub_form_field_widget)) {
                            $sub_form_field_widget = $sub_form_field_widget[0];
                            if (array_key_exists('value', $sub_form_field_widget)) {
                                // ON AJOUTE LE CHAMP AU FORMULAIRE
                                $form[$key][$field_key] = $sub_form[$field_key];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
//                // subform title
//                $sub_form['title']['#markup'] = '<p class="form-info">Informations friterie <span>(Obligatoire)</span></p>';
//
//                // Gestion préfix / suffix
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_pays']['#prefix'] = '<div class="row">';
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_ville']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_nom']['#prefix'] = '<div>';
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_telephone']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_menu_frites']['#prefix'] = '<p class="form-info">Menus <span>(Facultatif)</span></p><div class="row">';
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_menu_autre']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
//
//                // Gestion class
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_pays']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 no-label'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_code_postal']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 no-label'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_ville']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 no-label'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_adresse']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('no-label'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_nom']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('mid-display no-label'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_telephone']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('mid-display no-label'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_menu_frites']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_menu_viande']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_menu_sandwich']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_menu_autre']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_paiement_type']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('clear-panel-field third-display hide-required logo-checkboxes-container'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_budget']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('clear-panel-field panel-field-inline'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_sur_place']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('clear-panel-field panel-field-inline'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_photos_free']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('clear-panel-field'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_photos_pay_conf']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('clear-panel-field'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_photos_pay']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('clear-panel-field'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_site_web']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('inline-label'),
//                );
//                $sub_form['field_friterie_facebook']['#attributes'] = array(
//                    'class' => array('inline-label'),
//                );
            }
        }

        $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
        $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Submit'),
            '#button_type' => 'primary',
        );

        return $form;
    }

    public function cancelForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        drupal_set_message("cancel");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        drupal_set_message("validate");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        drupal_set_message("submitted");
    }

}
```